# Properly translating a conditional

Tags: translation, conditionals

> もしも君にめぐり逢えたら
>   二度と君の手を離さない

I would translate this to:

> Even if I could meet you by chance,
>   I would never leave your hand a second time.

That is because of the following analysis: moshi, if; mo, even; kimi, you; ni, preposition required by meguriau; meguriaetara, -tara form of potential of meguriau, meet by chance; nido to, a second time; kimi, you; no, possessive particle; te, hand; wo, object marker; hanasanai, negative present of hanasu, let go of. Trouble is, I've seen translations of this, which is from Time After Time by Mai Kuraki, which translate it more or less as:

> Even if I had met you by chance,
>   I would not have left your hand a second time.

But if hanasanai is present, why should I translate it with a past conditional? Wouldn't it make more sense to translate it as a present one? It *is* true that -tara contains the past suffix -ta, but so what? Does it necessarily imply a past action? And if so, why use the present in the apodosis?

Comment: past conditionalの訳(下の訳)は、間違えていると思います。present tense の訳(上の訳)でいいと思います。

Comment: To avoid having to look for it every time I read this: 訳＝わけ=translation, 間違える＝まちがえる=to be wrong.

Comment: I thought so too. But then why does [this site](http://www.animelyrics.com/jpop/maikuraki/timeaftertime.htm) use the past conditional? Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Yes, 訳 means "translation" but it's read as やく.　[訳]{わけ} means "reason"

Comment: Uh-huh, Google mistake :).

Comment: I think the translation on that site is making another same mistake: They translate "kimi to irozuku machi de deaetara" as the past conditional(If I could have met...) but it's obviously the present (or future) tense.

Comment: As both you and Choko note, the past tense in your sample translation isn't quite right. "*Would not have left* your hand" could be better rendered as "*would not let go of* your hand". "Would" here still makes for the correct English as this is all hypothetical and thus in the [subjunctive mood](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood).

Comment: Also, 二度と…〜ない is often better idiomatically rendered as "never ... [again]".

Comment: From your previous comment, @erikrutlendi, it seems you are saying would marks subjunctive mood. That is not true. Would marks a conditional mood, whereas the subjunctive (which in English is often the same as the indicative) is in the clause. Maybe I misunderstood the comment, but just to clarify this :).

Comment: Interesting. I'd been taught that the subjunctive covers both the first and second halves of conditional statements, and that the English conditional is expressed subjunctively. [This part of the Wikipedia article on conditionals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional) mentions the subjunctive just for the first half of the conditional. [This section on the English conditional](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood#English) touches on the "speculative", which I was taught was subjunctive, much as in the German. But perhaps not? 勉強になります。 :)

Comment: In some languages, e.g. Latin, that is true. In others, as Romanian and (maybe, I'm not sure) slavic ones, conditional is used in both halves. In English, like in Romance languages, it is if+subjunctive, and conditional. In German, besides the names which are strange, we have the present conditional, but then there is this use of the past Konjunktiv II instead of a past conditional, as Wikipedia says, which is strange to me. One should look into Old German to know the reason for this. Influence of Latin? Reminiscence of old use? Who knows.

Comment: Another thing to say is that the conditional is subjunctive (alias past) of will plus infinitive, so if one really wants to see subjunctives in both halves, well, that is how :).

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I would urge you to strike the Three Conditionals analysis from your brain (which is to say, that entire Wikipedia article), as it's a simplification for learners that's hopeless from a linguistics perspective.  I'd recommend consulting your favorite reference grammar instead, e.g. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002), which spends about a hundred pages on conditionals.

Comment: @snailboat: Rather that I don't have access to that source for the foreseeable future, what commentary does that have on conditionals and the subjunctive?  FWIW, my understanding of the subjunctive and conditionals predates Wikipedia by ... a while. :)  I'd learned that the subjunctive is what we call the "would have, should have, were I to ..." kinds of constructions for hypothetical and counterfactual statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if hanasanai is present, why should I translate it with a past conditional?

You shouldn't.

> Wouldn't it make more sense to translate it as a present one?

Indeed. Or a future tense.

> It is true that -tara contains the past suffix -ta, but so what? Does it necessarily imply a past action?

No. The -ta is aspectual, i.e. it explains what will happen "after having met" *you*. It works because 君の手を離さない happens after 君にめぐり逢えた.

The distinction of aspect and tense is subtle in Japanese, but as a very rough rule, I usually say that -ta (etc.) expresses **past tense** in matrix verbs, i.e. main clauses (usually the last verb in Japanese sentences), and **perfective aspect** in other positions (subclauses, relative clauses etc).

Comment: Perfect, just as I thought. Damn animelyrics confusing me :). Thanks.

Comment: Are there cases where the "rough rule" leads to errors?

Comment: @MickG, there's lots of cases where breaking the rule is at least an option, such as "past tense commands" (どいたどいた！) and historical present (史的現在).